# Is StreamInputFormat supported by Hadoop Job API?

Tags: xml, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to process xml files using Hadoop's StreamInputFormat. And I am using the newer API(Hadoop-0.20.205.0) for this.But, it seems Job doesn't support StreamInputFormat, as when I am trying to set the property through "job.setInputFormatClass(StreamInputFormat.class)", it is showing -

```
"The method setInputFormatClass(Class<? extends InputFormat>) in the type Job is not pplicable for the arguments (Class<StreamInputFormat>)"
```

I have even downloaded "hadoop-streaming-0.20.205.0.jar" explicitly and imported the "org.apache.hadoop.streaming" package, still no luck.Any suggestions??

Comment: Tariq, are you having a specific problem? This sort of question (in it's current state) isn't the sort of thing that's encouraged on stack overflow - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Chris..is it ok now?..or do I need to change it?

Comment: can you share some of your driver (main) code, where you're configuring this. When you say new API, are you using Job or JobConf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use an old-api InputFormat (mapred) with the new API client Job (mapreduce).

`Job.setInputFormat()` is expecting a class extending `o.a.h.mapreduce.InputFormat` (the new 'mapreduce' API), where as the streaming API is all written in the old API ('mapred' package), and `StreamInputFormat` extends `o.a.h.mapred.KeyValueTextInputFormat`, which in turn extends `o.a.h.mapred.FileInputFormat` (both of which are the old API):

- http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/release-0.20.205.0/src/contrib/streaming/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/streaming/StreamInputFormat.java?view=markup

Comment: thank you for the response Chris..is there some way to use it with the new API (i.e Job)??I tried casting Job to JobConf, but it didn't work..Actually I wanted to avoid using the older API..or shall I go with JobConf only??Apologies  if I am asking the very basics.I am still in the learning phase.

Comment: You'll need to port the Input format to the new API, if it hasn't already been done (should be simple enough). Are you wanting to write MR code in python / ruby / c? Why are you interested in the streaming API if you're writing java code to invoke the job?

Comment: I am using Java and opted for streaming as I could not find anything suitable for XML processing anywhere else..also I did not want to use Mahout's XMLInputFormat